# Pycharm debugger cherrypy restart causes keyboardinterrupt

Tags: pycharm, cherrypy

I use CherryPy to serve a DJANGO app. Below the code for starting the server:

```
log_info("Starting main server")
    cherrypy.config.update({
        'server.socket_host': self.host,
        'server.socket_port': self.port,
        'engine.autoreload_on': False,
        'log.screen': True
    })
    self.mount_static(settings.STATIC_URL, settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0])

    cherrypy.log("Loading and serving Django application")
    cherrypy.tree.graft(WSGIHandler())
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    log_info("Main server is running at http://%s:%d" % (self.host, self.port))
    #self.open_browser()
    if block:
        cherrypy.engine.block()

    log_info("Main server shutdown!")
```

When I call cherrypy.engine.restart() from code, the server nicely restarts. If I do the same thing when running in the PyCharm debugger, a KeyboardException is reported upon (re-)startup. This causes the entire application to stop. This must be something in relation to the PyCharm debugger (running on OS X), but I can't figure out what it might be.

Any help to make this work while running in debug would be very welcome.

Thanks.